# Any other method instead of relationship in laravel5.6?

Tags: relational-database, laravel-5.6

My project is in live. I failed to do relationship for two tables(Purchase and User).

Now what i try to do is to, Show all customer purchased amount along with his details, who all purchased from particular shop.

Here, purchase table contain CardNo and Amount and User table contain his CardNo and Image. How can i display correct CardNo and Amount and Image for ever one purchased from particular shop?

Only way to do Relationship(If so help me...) or any one with other good method to try.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the 2 tables together - eloquent has methods to easily achieve this.

You could, for example, do the following:

`Purchase::join('users', 'users.cardNo', '=', 'purchases.cardNo')->get();`

You should also read the documentation which Laravel provides as this also demonstrates how to do this inside your model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Can i use without mentioning relationship between two tables??

Comment: This will use SQL to join your table and the join doesn't need to be explicitly created in your database